# Is there a function in Swift that only runs during the first time opening the app?

Tags: ios, core-data

I'm currently making a dictionary app and I'm re-parsing through the json file that contains all the entries of the dictionaries every time I open the app and saving it to CoreData. I was wondering if there is a function in Swift that just runs once when the app is downloaded and then doesn't run again.

Comment: if you are using coredata already, why dont you save the user and have a "firstboot" flag, that gets set?

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: You can create a key in NSUserDefaults and call it something like MyAppFirstLaunched, and check it when the app launches. If it's false, do the parsing and set it to true.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to actually have the parsed dictionary in the persistent store when the user downloads your app? I don't see the point of parsing a JSON file at the user's end when you can just provide the date in the bundle.

Comment: I just started Swift a few days ago and I'm just writing an app to learn! But I will look into that for sure! If it isn't too much trouble would you be able to provide me with the link?

Answer (score 5):

What you can do set a NSUserDefaults to check whether it is a first run or not:

```
let firstRun = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("firstRun") as Bool
if !firstRun {
    //run your function
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "firstRun")
}
```

Comment: Just a question how were you able to come up with this? Did you read the documentation yourself, if so do you have any tips? I've just started Swift and I'm unable to understand the documentation, any advice?

Comment: The documentation you want is the Programming Guides. Don't try to start with the References; they're references, not introductions. The Programming Guides are what teach you how to use the technologies. This one is detailed in the Preferences and Settings Programming Guide. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html. You can find the available guides here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/#section=Resource%20Types&topic=Guides

Comment: There is a ton of documentation on this in the [Preferences and Settings Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000059i)

Comment: The key is that you need to learn Cocoa, not just "Swift." Swift is a very small piece of iOS development. Most of it is understanding the frameworks (Foundation, UIKit, Core Graphics, etc., often collectively called "Cocoa"). See also https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/RoadMapiOS/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011343-CH2-SW1 and https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Conceptual/iPhoneOSTechOverview/iPhoneOSTechnologies/iPhoneOSTechnologies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007898-CH3-SW1

Comment: plus if you find all the documentation bit overwhelming follow http://raywenderlich.com

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4 example:

In your ViewController

```
let firstRun = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "firstRun") as Bool
```

Then in your viewDidLoad

```
if firstRun {
    //function you want to run normally
} else {
    runFirst() //will only run once
}
```

Then make this function down below

```
func runFirst() {
    print("FIRST RUN!")
    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "firstRun")
}
```